# what is the result of (54.125) - (184)10

Tags: binary, floating-point, decimal, precision, floating

I am practicing for midterm and apprently there's no answer key for it.
However, I practiced and got a result but not sure if this is correct since the solution is really long.

> perfrom the following aritmetic operations using the 10 bit floating point standard(given on equation sheet)
> -I need to convert to normalized
> -standardize properly
> -convert final answer to normalized 10 bit.
> -convert the final answer to decimal.
> -must indicate if there is any loss of precision

my solution is really long so I'm just gonna post only answer here.

-normalized

> : 54.125 = 0 1100 10110
>
> : 184    = 0 1110 01110

-standardized:

> 54.125 = 0 1110 0.01101
>
> 184   = 0 1110 1.01110

-result :

> 0 0010 0000
>
> -denormalized: 0.03125
>
> -precision lost: -129.90625

please help thanks!

Comment: There is a meta entry on this sort of question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316493/is-my-answer-right-questions

Comment: Your "precision lost" is far too big, and the sign is incorrect. I can't check the steps because I don't have the equation sheet with the definition of the floating point format, but something has to be wrong.

Comment: I meant the sign of the result. You are subtracting a larger positive number from a smaller positive number, so you should get a negative result, roughly in the region of -130.